# Blue line appearing after second click on image

Tags: html, css

I don't really know how to write this because i have never seen a problem like this before.

If you go on this website (http://multicopterphoto.no/bolig/) Then click the image of the house. The image preview will appear. Go out of the preview. Now when you hover over the house again you will see a blue line around the circle.

I thought first it was something with the anchor tags, like text-decoration or something but it isn't.

Can you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you must set style to the `+` element

```
a .expand .ashit{
    outline: 0;
}
```

More info at [**Remove Dotted Link Borders**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-dotted-link-borders/)

Comment: Cant accept a answer before i has gone 15 mins from when i posted @Farshad

Comment: note that you have an error too at line 34 `$('#myModal').modal('show')`

Comment: I know, its not and error actually. The error does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
.expand.ashit{
    outline: 0;
}
```

Just add it to your css styles. That's it.

Comment: Thank you. Farshad was first so i accept his answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `outline` appearing on `:focus`

ADD `.overlay > a:focus {outline-style: none;}` to your CSS, This will solve your problem.